# Select data with limit on each column value

Tags: mysql, select, limit

Consider the following table:

```
id int primary_key
user_id int
type enum('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
```

with actual state:

```
id user_id type
1  2       type1
2  2       type1
3  2       type1
4  2       type1
5  2       type2
```

I'd like to write a select, which returns rows with id: 1,2,3,5;
I'd like to select all rows for user_id = 2, while selecting only max 3 of each type. Row with id=4 would not be selected, because it would have already found 3 rows with type1.

One way to do it is to create 3 seperate query for each value of type and then making an UNOIN of them. Is there a better/more efficient way?

Comment: have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table yt
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM your_table ty
       WHERE ty.type = yt.type
       AND ty.id <= yt.id
      ) <= 3;
```

I think this might help you.